# How are the short forms of Russian patronymics formed?

Tags: узус, выбор-имени

I stumbled upon Nikolaych, which I assume is a short form of Nikolayevich.

1. Do all Russian patronymics have such forms?
2. Is there a simple rule to form them? Please give examples.
3. How are they used in real life? Only when addressing someone or also in written?

Comment: 1. No. For example, Ilyich and Petrovna are never reduced. 2. What you took for short forms are merely phonetic reductions. 3. Clear articulation of '-yevich' is not often encountered in informal speech, even though almost always retained in writing (except when the writer wants to give a character's speech a kind of rustic touch).

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy, your comment looks like a decent answer...

Comment: Another interesing examples: Александрович-Саныч, Михайлович-Михалыч

Comment: @Schullz Because _Саня_ is a short form for _Александр_. Thus Александр Александрович is typically transformed into _Сан Саныч_ (cf. Павел Павлович --> Пал Палыч).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. *Do all Russian patronymics have such forms?* No. For example, Ilyich and Petrovna are never reduced.
2. *Is there a simple rule to form them?* What you took for short forms are merely phonetic reductions. Therefore, they are formed by some kind of a natural process. When unstressed, elaborate suffixes such as *-yevich*, *-ovich*, *-yevna*, *-ovna* are reduced, the ultimate forms being *-ich* (*i* often being slightly iotified), *-ych*, *-na*, *-vna*: *Andre<s>yev</s>ich*->*Andreich*, *Ivan<s>ov</s>ich*->*Ivanych*, *Ivan<s>ov</s>na*->*Ivanna*, *Nikola<s>yev</s>na*->*Nikolavna*.

   Reductions may affect the stem of the word: *Mikha<s>i</s>l<s>ov</s>ich*->*Mikhalych*, *Andre<s>ye</s>vna*->*Andrevna*. Name and patronymic of someone you're quite familiar with often form a tightly coupled compound which is pronounced as if it were a single word with stress on the name, heavily reduced: *Mikha<s>i</s>l Ivan<s>ov</s>ich*->*Mikhalyvanych*, or even *Mikhalvanch*, *Mar<s>ya</s> Ivan<s>ov</s>na*->*Marivanna*.

   The sounds that fall out may not vanish entirely. In fact, when they do so, it is perceived as something somewhat coarse and rustic; however, between good friends that may be a sign of cordiality, reproach etc.
3. *How are they used in real life?* Clear articulation of unstressed *-yevich*, *-ovich*, *-ovna* or *-yevna* is done only to help someone with spelling. Otherwise they are reduced even in formal context. *-ich* and *-inichna* are always stressed and therefore pronounced quite clearly.

   *Only when addressing someone or also in written?* Original forms of names and patronymics are almost always retained in writing (except for example when the writer wants to give a character's speech a kind of uneducated touch). There are also some special usages. For example, *Marivanna* is an archetypal teacher often appearing in [Vovochka jokes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_jokes#Vovochka).

Answer (score 4):

If the father's name ends in *-й* (like *Андре**й***, *Серге**й***, *Тимофе**й***, *Никола**й***, etc.), the masculine form of the patronymic ends in an unstressed *-евич* [jɪvɪtʃ], e.g. *Андреевич* [ənˈdrejɪvɪtʃ]. In this case in the colloquial language this *-евич* [jɪvɪtʃ] can be shortened/reduced to *-[й]ич* [(j)ɪtʃ] with the final *-й* of the father's name dropping out or not, depending on the speaker, so

> *Андреевич* [ənˈdrejɪvɪtʃ] > *Андре[й]ич* [ənˈdre(j)ɪtʃ]
>
> *Николаевич* [nɪkəˈlɑjɪvɪtʃ] > *Никола[й]ич* [nɪkəˈlɑ(j)ɪtʃ]

If the father's name ends in another consonant (like *Степа**н***, *Кири**лл***, *Вади**м***, etc.), then the masculine form of the patronymic ends in an unstressed *-ович* [əvɪtʃ], e.g. *Степанович* [stɪ'pɑnəvɪtʃ]. In this case in the colloquial language this *-ович* [əvɪtʃ] can be shortened/reduced to *-ыч* [ɨtʃ], so

> *Степанович* [stɪ'pɑnəvɪtʃ] >  *Степаныч* [stɪ'pɑnɨtʃ]
>
> *Кириллович* [kɪ'riləvɪtʃ] > *Кирилыч* [kɪ'rilɨtʃ]

This, however, does not apply to some names, e.g. although *Оле**г*** ends in a consonant, you can hardly hear somebogy saying **Олегыч*, since the sound combination *гы* is normally not found in Russian.

Also, *Петрович* has no reduced form, since *Пётр* is a monosyllabic name and the suffix *-ович* is stressed in it, so it cannot be reduced.

And some names have irregular colloquial patronymics mentioned by [Schullz](https://russian.stackexchange.com/users/6131/schullz) and [user4419802](https://russian.stackexchange.com/users/5008/user4419802) in the comments to the question:

> *Алексáндрович* > *Сáныч*
>
> *Михáйлович* > *Михáлыч*
>
> *Пáвлович* > *Пáлыч*